# Telescope question

Tags: the-moon

During the daylight, you hold a ruler in a distance of 60 cm away from your eyes, and you find
the size of the Moon to be 0.55 cm (try it yourself!). At night, you use a telescope to observe rock
formations and craters on the Moon to estimate the diameter of the Moon to be about 3500 km.
Find the distance to the Moon by using only the information from this experiment

Comment: I think this question should be closed, as this forum is not meant to help you solve problems from ongoing competitions (such as this one).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question.  You have copied a homework task to the question box.  Sorry but we can't do your homework for you.  If you have a question that can be answered you can ask here. You will need to show what you have already tried and you will need to make your question specific.

Comment: @JamesK Actually, James, we do allow homework questions here: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/6. That said, I do think an exception should be made in this case since this is for an open competition.